# Pass the value of the ACF field to the hidden Ninja forms field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, ninja-forms

There is an ACF field group. This group has a repeater field. In the repeater, a text field whose value must be passed to the hidden field of the Ninja Forms form.

Key a hidden field Ninja Forms «cost_1565849718636». ACF group «group_5d489118f0d20», repeater field «field_5d48911907c30», text sub field «field_5d48933edcdd7».

I will be grateful for the help, just learning)

I tried it, but it doesn't work. Perhaps because the ACF field is in the repeater?

```php
    function nf_hidden_field_values( $value, $field_type, $field_settings ) {
        global $post;

        if ( $field_settings['key'] == 'cost_1565849718636' ) {
            return get_field('field_5d48933edcdd7', $post->ID);
        }

        return $value;
    }
    add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_default_value', 'nf_hidden_field_values', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itself asked - itself answered). Can someone come in handy)

```php
    add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_default_value', 'wm_the_value' , 10 , 3);
    function wm_the_value( $default_value, $field_type, $field_settings ) {
        if ( $field_settings['key'] == 'cost1') {
            if ( have_rows( 'field_5d48911905103' ) ) {
                while ( have_rows( 'field_5d48911905103' ) ) { the_row();
                    if( have_rows('field_5d48911907c30') ){
                        while( have_rows('field_5d48911907c30') ){ the_row();
                            $default_value = get_sub_field('field_5d48933edcdd7');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $default_value;
    }
```